# while running django command from docker compose it says "sh: django: not found"

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created docker image and when i run `docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django --version"` the output is `sh: django: not found`

requirements.txt:-

```
Django>=3.2.4,<3.3
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<3.13
```

Dockerfile:-

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="ayush270702"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV="true" ]; \
        then /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \    
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"   
   

USER django-user
```

docker-compose.yml:-

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

After running `docker build .` and `docker-compose build` django is getting installed and image is getting created successfully,
but when I run

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "django --version"
```

**output:**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUx40.png)

I tried removing virtual env from Dockerfile but output was same

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="ayush270702"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements.dev.txt /tmp/requirements.dev.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=false
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV="true" ]; \
        then pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \    
    rm -rf /tmp && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        django-user

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"   
   

USER django-user
```

Comment: use `python -m` as `docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python -m django --version" `

Comment: Thanks its working for me this way but while using command **docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python -m django --version"** its giving me same error i.e, **No module named django-admin**

Comment: why don't you share the docker log command output on your containers. The error which you have share in the question is too little scope to understand what is wrong!